# Can we have $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For $n \geq 5$ can we have $x^3\equiv 1 \pmod n$. And if so for what $n$?

I was thinking that we need $x^2 \equiv x^{-1}$ but I cant see when thats possible if possible.

Regards.

Comment: For $n=7$, we clearly have $2^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. Do you know what the primitive element theorem is?

Comment: I am confused, in the title it says $x^3 \equiv 1$ while in the post itself it says $n^3 \equiv 1$, is it the second one?

Comment: $n^3=0\mod n$. What is the question?

Comment: Did you mean $x^3\equiv 1\pmod n$ (where $x$ and $n$ may be different) or $n^3\equiv 1\pmod n$?  You have one version in the title and the other in the question.

Comment: sorry i meant x

Comment: @CalvinLin no, I don't know modern algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course we can, take $\bmod 3^k$, the multiplicative group $\bmod 3^k$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2\cdot3^{k-1}}$, since cyclic groups have exactly one subgroup of each order that divides the order of the group there are exactly $2$ elements of order $3$.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are asking following question:

> For what integer $n \ge 5$, we can find an integer $x$ such that
>   $$x \not\equiv 1 \pmod n \quad\text{ and }\quad x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod n\tag{*1}$$

The answer is

> Such a $x$ exists if and only if $\;9 | n\;$ or $n$ contains a prime factor of the form $3k+1$.

It is too bad I cannot come up with a completely elementary proof. 
Following derivations need some knowledge of group theory.

---

If such a $x$ exists, then $\;x (x^2) = x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod n\;$ implies $x$ belongs
to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, the 
[multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)
consisting of congruence classes of integers relative prime to the modulus number $n$.
It is known that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ contains $\varphi(n)$ elements where $\varphi(\cdot)$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

For any $x \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, the condition $(*1)$ is equivalent to
the question whether the order of $x$ is $3$ or not. If such a $x$ exists, then by a well known corollary of [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29),

$$3 = \text{order}(x) \;|\; \# (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times = \varphi(n)$$

On the other direction, if $3 | \varphi(n)$, then by 
[Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29),
the finite group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ contains an element of order $3$.
Combine these, we find such a $x$ exists if and only if $3 | \varphi(n)$.

Let $n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_r^{e_r}$ be the factorization of $n$ into its prime factors. By [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem),

$$
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \simeq 
\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{e_1}\mathbb{Z} \times
\mathbb{Z}/p_2^{e_2}\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots
\mathbb{Z}/p_r^{e_r}\mathbb{Z} \\
\implies
(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times \simeq 
(\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{e_1}\mathbb{Z})^\times \times
(\mathbb{Z}/p_2^{e_2}\mathbb{Z})^\times \times \cdots
(\mathbb{Z}/p_r^{e_r}\mathbb{Z})^\times
\tag{*2}
$$
This leads to
$$\varphi(n) = \varphi(p_1^{e_1}) \varphi(p_2^{e_2}) \cdots \varphi(p_r^{e_r})
= (p_1-1)p_1^{e_1-1} \cdot (p_2-1)p_2^{e_2-1} \cdots (p_r-1)p_r^{e_r-1}$$

From this, it is easy to see there are two ways for $\;3 | \varphi(n)\;$, namely:

- $3$ appear as one of the $p_i$ and the corresponding exponent $e_i > 1$.
- $3$ is a factor of one of $p_i - 1$.

i.e. $(*1)$ has a solution if and only if $\;9|n\;$ or $n$ contains a prime factor of the form $3k+1$.

We know for odd prime $p$, groups of the form $( \mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z} )^\times$ is a [cyclic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group). 
A cyclic group of order $m$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $3$ if and only if $3 | m$. 
If exists, the cyclic subgroup is unique.
Since $(*2)$ tell us $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is a direct product, we find:

> The number of solutions for $(*1)$ is equal to $3^{s+t} - 1$ where
>
> - $s = 1$ when $\;9|n\;$ and $0$ otherwise.
> - $t$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ of the form $3k+1$.